# T-SQL (SQL SERVER) - Rename Database Error Msg

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to rename my database but I'm not familiar with the syntax. I've tried 2 different things but get the following error msgs...

**Method 1:**

```
DECLARE @old varchar(100)
DECLARE @new varchar(100)
SET @old = 'ver.1'
SET @new = 'ver.2'

DECLARE @query varchar(max)
set @query = 'ALTER DATABASE @old MODIFY NAME = @new'
exec @query
```

**Error**: Could not find stored procedure 'ALTER DATABASE @old MODIFY NAME = @new'.

---

**Method 2:**

```
DECLARE @old varchar(100)
DECLARE @new varchar(100)
SET @old = 'ver.1'
SET @new = 'ver.2'

ALTER DATABASE @old MODIFY NAME = @new
```

**Error**: Incorrect syntax near @old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stop using `exec` for dynamic SQL; use `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql). Also, you can't inline parameterize arguments to `ALTER DATABASE` that way - you need to use string concatenation. Finally, because you chose to use illegal characters in your database name (`.`), you need to escape these with `QUOTENAME`.

```
DECLARE @old varchar(100) = 'ver.1';
DECLARE @new varchar(100) = 'ver.2';

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ALTER DATABASE ' 
  + QUOTENAME(@old) + ' MODIFY NAME = ' + QUOTENAME(@new) + ';';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use sp_renamedb to rename database.

```
EXEC sp_renamedb 'old_name' , 'new_name'
```